# Dataframe wide to long format

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

I'm having trouble converting my date from wide to long format in R.

This is an exemplary dataframe (mine is much larger, but just for you to understand).

```
    CASE   Val1     Val2    Val3    Val4     Age
1   149       1        3       5       4      22
2   150       3        2       3       2      30
3   151       1        2       6       4      34
4   152       3        4       5       5      27
5   153       2        3       1       3      29
6   154       5        5       2       4      20  
7   155       6        2       5       2      41  
8   156       3        1       1       1      26  
9   157       1        1       4       5      21  
10  158       2        3       5       4      36
```

My goal is to have a dataframa, that shows me for each CASE the Age and the values, not in wide format (using multiple columns), but rather long format -> resulting in only three columns. This means that in my new data frame the CASE number will be repeated as many times there are values for it, with the right Age and data (Val1, Val2, Val3, and Val4).

This is how I want it to look basically (the # is to show where the Val is coming from):

```
    CASE   Age     Val           
1   149     22      1    # (Val1)
2   149     22      3    # (Val2)  
3   149     22      5    # (Val3) 
4   149     22      4    # (Val4)   
5   150     30      3    # (Val1)       
6   150     30      2    # (Val2)      
7   150     30      3    # (Val3)       
8   150     30      2    # (Val4)     
9   151     34      1    # (Val1)      
10  151     34      2    # (Val2)     
... and so on
```

I have tried reshape, melt, gather, pivot_longer, and so on, but I can't get R to assemble the Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4 in that order from top to bottom only within three columns.

Solutions on GitHub show vectors, that need to be specified beforehand. Do I have to specify each values (Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4) as vectors for it to work? The problem with this is, that my dataframe is much larger and available in a CSV. Data format, that I have uploaded into R-Studio. I have pages full of colums and rows, how could I extract a column as a vector then (since this is only an exemplary dataframe)? How do I call upon columns, within a big dataframe and only work with a selected number out of them (here CASE, Age, and Val1-4).

Example:

```
long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(data, cols = -CASE, 
                    names_to = c('variable', 'system'), names_sep = '_')
```

What do I have to write in "names_to" within that vector, if Val basically bascially must be one vector consisting of Val1, Val2, Val3, and Val4? I have tried to save Val as a vector...

```
Val <- c(Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4)
```

and then insert it, but it didn't work. Maybe because Val1-4 are just simple columns within my big dataframe? If so, I could not find a way to extract them as vectors.

Comment: You have `Age` in both the wide and long formats, is there a reason you are not excluding it with case, as in `cols=-c(CASE, Age)`? That seems an obvious first-step.

Comment: The thing is I have a huge dataframe, of which Val1-4 and Age are just a handful. Does that mean I have to exclude all of the other columns? Why can't I just select the columns I want and convert them into long format, instead of taking my huge dataframe and one by one exclude each column that is not either Val1-4 or Age?

Comment: I can't really say for certain, KalilaA, but it doesn't matter: if you have a column in the input that you need to be unchanged in the output, you _must_ include it in the `cols= -c(..)` exclusion. Period. If you don't put it there, it will be pivoted into your value columns, which is likely annoying at best, requiring a bit of work to bring back into each group of data. This is just the nature of pivoting. (Or ... you can just remove it outright. I'm just trying to advise how to get what you say you need here.)

Comment: Ok, is there a way to specifically choose what comes into values_to= () ? For now it just includes everything that is not specifically excluded. If not, then I would have to extract Val1-4 into a seperate dataframe, for the code to only use those columns into Val, I guess.. Oh and I forgot to thank you for the cols=-c(), it really helped!

Comment: If you want some columns to be _neither_ id columns _nor_ pivoted into value columns, can you remove them pre-pivot?

Answer (score 0):

First we can `pivot_longer` (excluding the CASE and Age columns), the Val* columns' values go into `Val` whilst the column names go into `name_to_delete` (that we can remove):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(CASE, Age),
               names_to = "names_to_delete",
               values_to = "Val") |>
  select(-names_to_delete)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 40 × 3
    CASE   Age   Val
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   149    22     1
 2   149    22     3
 3   149    22     5
 4   149    22     4
 5   150    30     3
 6   150    30     2
 7   150    30     3
 8   150    30     2
 9   151    34     1
10   151    34     2
# … with 30 more rows
```

Comment: I either get only two columns, meaning CASE and one column that groups every other column under Val (including Age and other columns I have in my dataframe) or once I specify the specific column of Age as so -> data$Age, I get this error message "Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`: ! Can't combine `2` <character> and `8` <double>."

I don't understand, because Age and CASE are numeric and not chr?

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly without having any other data than the one you posted (where the code works). You could try specifying `starts_with("Val")` instead of `-c(CASE, Age)` in the code above. Can you post the code that gives you the error?